# Is there a shorcut to jump to another layout in sublime text3?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext3

We can make a view with two layouts columns in sublime text 3. And when I want to type in another layout I always click to this layout so I don't want to click. I want to use shortcut. Is there such a shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question is `super+k super+left` and `super+k super+right`
Here are the shortcuts directly from Default keybidings.
If you're on Window `super` in `Control` key and if you're on Mac `super` is `Command`

```
{ "keys": ["super+k", "super+up"], "command": "new_pane" },
{ "keys": ["super+k", "super+shift+up"], "command": "new_pane", "args": {"move": false} },
{ "keys": ["super+k", "super+down"], "command": "close_pane" },
{ "keys": ["super+k", "super+left"], "command": "focus_neighboring_group", "args": {"forward": false} },
{ "keys": ["super+k", "super+right"], "command": "focus_neighboring_group" },
{ "keys": ["super+k", "super+shift+left"], "command": "move_to_neighboring_group", "args": {"forward": false} },
{ "keys": ["super+k", "super+shift+right"], "command": "move_to_neighboring_group" },
```